# Build failed of multi-flavor for Gradle 3.0.0+

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I have three modules, one `app` and two library modules, `common` and `sdk`. The dependency is `app` -> `common` -> `sdk` .

Flavor config of build.gradle of `app`

```
flavorDimensions "default"

productFlavors {
    merchant {
        dimension "default"
    }
    consumer {
        dimension "default"
    }
}
```

Flavor config of build.gradle of `common`

```
flavorDimensions "default"

productFlavors {
    merchant {
        dimension "default"
    }
    consumer {
        dimension "default"
        missingDimensionStrategy 'default', 'consumerABC' // for library dependency includes a flavor dimension that your app does not.
        matchingFallbacks = ['consumerABC'] // for app includes flavors that the library does not.
    }
}
```

Flavor config of build.gradle of `sdk`, here is what the difference of flavor with other modules, the one of flavor name is not matched for some reason.

```
flavorDimensions "default"

productFlavors {
    merchant {
        dimension "default"
    }
    consumerABC {
        dimension "default"
    }
}
```

But got the exception while build project:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processConsumerDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:consumerDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :sdk.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :common
      > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :sdk:
          - Configuration 'consumerABCDebugApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'consumerABCDebug' but wasn't required.
              - Required default 'consumer' and found incompatible value 'consumerABC'.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
          - Configuration 'consumerABCDebugRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'consumerABCDebug' but wasn't required.
              - Required default 'consumer' and found incompatible value 'consumerABC'.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Configuration 'consumerABCReleaseApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'consumerABCRelease' but wasn't required.
              - Required default 'consumer' and found incompatible value 'consumerABC'.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
          - Configuration 'consumerABCReleaseRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'consumerABCRelease' but wasn't required.
              - Required default 'consumer' and found incompatible value 'consumerABC'.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Configuration 'merchantDebugApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'merchantDebug' but wasn't required.
              - Required default 'consumer' and found incompatible value 'merchant'.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
          - Configuration 'merchantDebugRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'merchantDebug' but wasn't required.
              - Required default 'consumer' and found incompatible value 'merchant'.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
          - Configuration 'merchantReleaseApiElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'merchantRelease' but wasn't required.
              - Required default 'consumer' and found incompatible value 'merchant'.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' and found incompatible value 'java-api'.
          - Configuration 'merchantReleaseRuntimeElements':
              - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'release'.
              - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found compatible value 'Aar'.
              - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'merchantRelease' but wasn't required.
              - Required default 'consumer' and found incompatible value 'merchant'.
              - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-runtime' and found compatible value 'java-runtime'.
```

Basically I just followed the document of [Use variant-aware dependency management](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_aware). This issue has been annoying a while, hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: If change the flavor name `consumerABC` to `consumer` it will work well as expected (say automatically matching)

Comment: is `sdk` used by `common`? or `app`? or both?

Comment: `sdk` used by `common` and `common` used by `app`. Thanks, I need to update for it.

Comment: Try removing `missingDimensionStrategy` since it's in the wrong place and you actually don't need it since you don't have a missing dimension - every module has a `default` dimension. You only need the fallback. Also try building directly from common to see if it works.

Comment: @ltai-hanski Have tried. It got the same exception. Any else idea?